# Activity notified by an IntentService

Tags: android

I have an IntentService and have to send a broadcast to the client activity for updating the UI. Where is the best place to do this? Is it ok to send it from the onHandleIntent method? Or is there a method (in the main thread) that gets called when the onHandleIntent method is over?

Answer (score 1):

Sending the broadcast in `onHandleIntent` is the right place if you want to send the broadcast upon receipt of the intent.